# webpack-dev-server: How to open browser with Node.js API?

Tags: webpack-dev-server

This is my script:

```
const webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./config');
const options = {
  contentBase: './dist',
  hot: true,
  hotOnly: true,
  open: true,
  host: 'localhost'
};

webpackDevServer.addDevServerEntrypoints(config, options);
const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = new webpackDevServer(compiler, options);

server.listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

The browser didn't open automatically. So how to make happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same issue. As far as I know there are some bugs in webpack 'open' option implementations, which I don't wish to dig deep into. I successfully use a workaround found by [gluons](https://github.com/gluons/vue-pack/commit/27317dc70ae87d9a69f4b55d5c4ea254043bd3b4)

Though, In my case it appeared enough just to add opn(myUrl) to the end of my webpack dev-server.js file. In my case the 'opn' package was preinstalled already, but if you don't have it preinstalled you can add it to dependencies as shown in gluons' solution.

Hope it'll work for you, too.